# SQL trigger, insert into statement

Tags: mysql, sql, triggers, insert, where-clause

I have two sql tables called `scan_sc` and `rescan_rsc`. The scan table looks like this:

```
CREATE TABLE scan_sc 
( 
   id_sc int(4), 
   Type_sc varchar(255), 
   ReScan_sc varchar(255), 
   PRIMARY KEY  (id_sc)
)
```

When a scan a document I insert a row into the scan table. If the result of this scanning is poor I have to do a rescan, and therefore I have a rescan table.

```
CREATE TABLE rescan_rsc 
(
   id_rsc int(4), 
   Scan_rsc varchar(255), 
   PRIMARY KEY  (id_rsc)
)
```

The problem is, I want to have a trigger that will fill in the column `ReScannet_sc` with an `"x"`, in the `scan_sc` table, so I can see that there has been some problems here.

The trigger has to do it where the id from the rescan table is the same as in the scan table.

Hope you all understand my question.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: **WHAT** database and which version?? **SQL** is just the Structured Query Language - a language used by **many** database systems - **SQL** is **NOT** a database product... stuff like this is very often **vendor-specific** - so we really need to know what **database system** you're using....

Comment: Neiter your  `scan_sc` nor your `rescan_rsc` tables have a column called `id_sd` yet that's the primary key for both??

Comment: its a mysql database. And primary key is now correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you really need the `ReScan_sc` column and the trigger?

With a simple `JOIN`, you can find out the records in your `scan_sc` table that have been re-scanned, without using the `ReScan_sc` column at all.
There are several possibilities:

Show all scans, with an additional column with the Rescan ID, if any:

```
SELECT scan_sc.*, rescan_sc.id_rsc
FROM scan_sc
LEFT JOIN rescan_sc ON scan_sc.id_sc = rescan_sc.id_rsc
```

Show only the scans which have been re-scanned:

```
SELECT scan_sc.*
FROM scan_sc
INNER JOIN rescan_sc ON scan_sc.id_sc = rescan_sc.id_rsc
```

(I assume that `id_sc` and `id_rsc` are the primary keys and that `PRIMARY KEY (id_sd)` is a typo, like marc_s pointed out in his comment)

Comment: Then i dont have a tabel, where the users can type in the rescanned documents, if i understand your solution correct.

Comment: You would still have both tables. The `rescan_sc` table would remain as it is, only the `Rescan_sc` column in the `scan_sc` table would be gone (and you wouldn't need the trigger at all).

Comment: You don't **have** to do it this way, this is just an alternative suggestion. You can still do it with a trigger if you want (but then I can't help you, because I don't know how to write triggers in MySQL).

Comment: I think i will use your answer, its much easier for me to understand. And i dont have much experience with triggers.